# creating a db schema

Tags: hyperref, formatting

I am trying to create a schema page in LaTeX. It shall look like this.

How can I create schema code which look like this image? There should be also a click to go function. When the user clicks on the user_schema link he should be redirected to that page.

What classes I can use for this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[Here is the code to see how it appears: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/53915feaeef2f99941486f56?r=380e068e&rs=ps&rm=d](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/53915feaeef2f99941486f56?r=380e068e&rs=ps&rm=d)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\section{User schema}
\mySchema{Users}
{
    _id: ObjectId - Id do registro
    name: String - Nome do usuário
    date: Date - Data de Cadastro
    ren_date: Date - Data de renovação do Cadastro
    email: String - Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet, consecteturadipisicingelit, sed do eiusmodtemporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimveniam, exercitationullamcolaborisnisi ut aliquipexeacommodoconsequat. Duisautereprehenderit in voluptatevelit esse cillumdolore eu fugiatnullapariatur. Occaecatcupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa quiofficiadeseruntmollit.
    access_log: Array [ 
        { 
            date: String - Data da ocorrência.
            user: ObjectId - Usuário que executou.
            action: String - Ação Executada.
        }
        { 
            date: String - Data da ocorrência.
            user: ObjectId - Usuário que executou.
            action: String - Ação Executada.
        }
    ]
    \link{group}{group_id}: ObjectId - Id do grupo.
}
\end{document}
```

Here is the image how should it appear:

[image: latex image]

Comment: The last blurry red "requirement" is a bit vague. *How* should a schema be split across the page boundary? Also, it would be great if you could enlighten us with something you've tried already... otherwise this do-it-for-me request might not get much attention.

Comment: I have added the link to my code. I meant schema length exceed page size then spliting it across new page. Ignore that point. I want to show two schema, each on diff page.

Comment: `hyperref` for links and `tcolorbox` for breakable schemas.

Comment: @Ignasi: I could see how to use `hyperref`, but content does not appear properly, I have give link to my live code, can you please see?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you. Content doesn't appear properly because you've not defined `\mySchema` environment and `\link` is not properly shown because doesn't exist any `\link` command. With `hyperref` package you can define links inside or outside your document, but you must know how to use them and `tcolorbox` could help you to define something similar to your intended `\mySchema` but you must define it. LaTeX is magic but not to such a level.

Comment: @Ignasi: thanks for help. `\mySchema{Users}` is it not the schema definition? `\link` is also I have used, can you please see : https://www.sharelatex.com/project/53915feaeef2f99941486f56?r=380e068e&rs=ps&rm=d

Comment: From your (author) point of view `\mySchema{Users}` could be the definition of an schema that you want to include in your text. But not for LaTeX. It doesn't know what do you mean for `\mySchema` because you have not previously defined and is not part of LaTeX commands/environments dictionary. If you fill your text with valid LaTeX commands, LaTeX will know what to do. Have you used LaTeX before?

Comment: @Ignasi: I am newbie with latex, while using sharelatex, when I typed `\mySchema` it was showing me in list of class. so i thought it might be there. can you please tell me is it possible to create doc which appeas in image? dont mind about color

Comment: @user2129623 You mentioned in your other question that you had solved points (1) and (2) highlighted there. Could you update the code in this question and integrate the points you mentioned there to make clear which problems you are still trying to solve? Please edit the code in the question and not on the site you link to. That ensures that the question will remain complete even if the code you link to changes or disappears in the future and saves people having to visit other sites in order to understand your question.