# formating document in latex

Tags: diagrams

I want document in specific database schema style. Like in image. I have tried as much I can do, even I am facing issue.

1. Why access_log & group_id coming up with indentation (I want all line indented similar)
2. Why text exceeds the page width? I tried with `\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in, paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}` , `\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}` but even text content exceed page wdith
3. In access_log, I want to create array as appearing in image. Is it possible?
4. Can I create title as it is `Users-schema` in image width black strip

**Link to Source code with DEMo :** https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5374a2ebeb2b8d651828ef64?r=380e068e&rs=ps&rm=d

Image:

[image]

Comment: You asked http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183390/creating-a-db-schema: how is this question different?

Comment: If you set the width of the paper to 5.5" and the width of the text block to 6.5" then it is not really surprising that the resulting text is wider than the width of the page ;). TeX does as you tell it. If you say the paper is 1mm wide but the text should be 3km, TeX will try to typeset a document using those dimensions. It won't always succeed and the results won't always look pretty when it does, but it will try. Take a look at the manual for the `geometry` package.

Comment: @JosephWright: no one answered that question. Here I made my own try and completed as much I can do. Everyone rather looking at my issue and try just keep closing the question, without looking that no one answered on that question as per my need. I also believe and accept  that I could not show enough efforts on that question

Comment: @cfr: dude, I really appreciate your comment and expertise. If I could have understood the problem, then I should not have asked it here, rather would have solved. I will check `geometry` package. 
But I surprise that 6 experts care to close, but none of them could correct minor mistakes of mine. Yes, I have just started working with  latex packages

Comment: I have figured out point 1 and 2 now

Comment: @user2129623 You can edit your other question to include the code etc. you posted here. That way, everything is in one place and you won't get a repeat closed as a duplicate. (Editing will also put your question back on the front page so it will be drawn to people's attention again.) This avoids cluttering things with duplicates and makes sure that a single question contains all of the relevant information you provide and that all efforts to help are focused in one place. So it avoids duplication of effort (on your part and ours) as well as duplication of content.